# Hide Comments by Default on SoundCloud

Tags: soundcloud

Is there a way I can hide comments by default on SoundCloud?

I saw the plugin for Chrome but I don't always use Chrome. Is there a better solution than that?

Comment: Relevant support thread: [How do i turn off comments in the player?](https://getsatisfaction.com/soundcloud/topics/how_do_i_turn_off_comments_in_the_player)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated 1-26-15**

Here's a tampermonkey/greasemonkey script that disables comments in Soundcloud new and classic view:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SoundCloud - Hide comments
// @description    Hides comments on tracks
// @include        http*://soundcloud.com/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("<style type='text/css'>"+ 
  ".waveformComments{ display:none !important;}" + 
  ".commentBubble__wrapper{ display:none !important;}" + 
  ".commentPopover{ display:none !important;}" + 
  ".waveform__layer.waveform__scene canvas:nth-child(2){ opacity:0 !important;}" +
  "</style>").appendTo("head");
```

Answer (score 5):

No there is no better solution currently than using a plugin or manually clicking the disable comments button.

Or you can use this userscript [SoundCloud - Hide Comments](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/90943)

This one, which is similar, does not work [SoundCloud Hide Comments](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/98339)

Answer (score 1):

The answer/script by phwd works well also, but you can short-hand it with:

```
$('.player').addClass('no-comments');
```

I tested in Chrome and Firefox (using the console).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Soundcloud did a partial redesign. I had to add this line to the answer from y3sh to get rid of the main comments section.

```
".commentsList{ display:none !important;}" +
```

Final solution includes y3sh's original.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SoundCloud - Hide comments
// @description    Hides comments on tracks
// @include        http*://soundcloud.com/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

/* globals $ */

$("<style type='text/css'>"+
  ".waveformComments{ display:none !important;}" +
  ".commentBubble__wrapper{ display:none !important;}" +
  ".commentPopover{ display:none !important;}" +
  ".waveform__layer.waveform__scene canvas:nth-child(2){ opacity:0 !important;}" +
  ".commentsList{ display:none !important;}" +
  "</style>").appendTo("head");
```